# Django - store excel file in a variable during an entire session

Tags: python, django, excel, python-3.x, pandas

I have developped multiples python functions that helps me process some data from an Excel file (using pandas library by the way). Those functions are able to read and process the file.

Now, I want to develop a web interface that can display the processed data to the users of the website.

To be more precise, when a user come on my web page :

- He'll upload an excel file (via an html form and using AJAX)
- Once the file is loaded on the server (via my reader function), he'll be able to choose some criteria to display the data he wants (using the other functions I developped to process the data).

The thing is, I want to reuse my code and how can I manage to store the excel file in a variable during the entire session of the user ?
I'm open to any other solution if you have any.

P.S : I use pandas.read_excel(MY_EXCEL_FILE) to read the excel file.

Thanks in advance

Comment: You don't want to store "file in the session", but you might be interested in saving file to some temporary location (/tmp for example) and save the path to that file in session under "current_file" key for example.

Comment: Sounds like a very good idea ! Thank you !